# My iframe will not center when sizing in my CSS doc but will when resize in HTML doc. I want it to be resized in CSS doc for good practice

Tags: html, css, iframe

So I have my iframe but left aligned but it wont center.

```css
.iframeContainer {
    display: inline-block;
    justify-content: center; /* Center the iframe horizontally */
    align-items: center;
    width: 1067px;
    height: 600px; 
}
```

```html
<div class="iframeContainer">
    <iframe width="100%" height="100%" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/vFO0_PA_NAg?si=VeD7R53zMk8l3yw8" title="YouTube video player" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture; web-share" allowfullscreen></iframe>
</div>
```

when I try and resize the iframe in the html Doc it works. For example:

```html
<div class="iframeContainer">
        <iframe width="1067px" height="600px" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/vFO0_PA_NAg?si=VeD7R53zMk8l3yw8" title="YouTube video player" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture; web-share" allowfullscreen></iframe>
</div>
```

then the CSS page would just like

```css
.iframeContainer {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center; 
    align-items: center;
}
```

I also tried putting the margin as auto... that didn't work either.

now I could be wrong so bear with me I am new to the coding world but I beilve an iframe is a block element so I am bewildered that it works as a flex.  I know it's good practice keep elements consistent so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You Can try to add <center>your iframe</center> in your HTML code might works as well

Comment: Did you also try display:block and margin: auto for iframe.

Comment: It's html5 so the center tag doesn't work.  As for the display block and margin: auto I tried that too... still didn't work.

Comment: First your display inline-block wont work with align-items: center; and justify-content. just remove them with the display: inline-block and add margin:auto and it will work you will have the horizontal alignment

Comment: _"but I beilve an iframe is a block element"_ - no, it is not. Put `<iframe></iframe><iframe></iframe>` into an empty document, and you will clearly see them showing up _next_ to each other, if there is enough space.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First your display inline-block wont work with align-items: center; and justify-content. just remove them with the display: inline-block and add margin:auto and it will work you will have the horizontal alignment: check it full page in the snippet below. As iframeContainer div display as block (not inline block) so we need to use margin: auto

```css
.iframeContainer {
    width: 1067px;
    height: 600px; 
    margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="iframeContainer">
        <iframe width="100%" height="100%" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/vFO0_PA_NAg?si=VeD7R53zMk8l3yw8" title="YouTube video player" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture; web-share" allowfullscreen></iframe>
</div>
```